# Python: Sorting a list of substrings without creating a separate copy of each substring

Tags: python, string, memory, copy

I have a really long string and need to create a list of substrings that start on each item in the string and go all the way to the end. For example...

```
longstring= "some huge string"
substring_list=[longstring[x:] for x in range(len(longstring))]
```

Then I need to sort substring_list alphabetically.
I'm using cython to try to run this in C to make things faster (required for later parts of the script).
However, when I run my code I promptly run out of memory (as soon as I attempt to create substring_list) and my script is getting killed. I thought by slicing a string I was merely creating a link to a slice of longstring, and that this wouldn't require much additional memory. Is that not true?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: `sorted(substring_list)` doesn't work? Why are you creating so many substrings? Can't you find a way to break down your `longstring`?

Answer (score 1):

Slicing Python built-in classes (like `list`, `tuple` but also `str`) generally creates a new object. It **could** share the underlying C-character-array with the original but that would be an implementation detail. Even if it's implemented (and I assume it isn't) it might depend on the version of python (python 2.x, python 3.x, ...) you're using or which python (CPython, PyPy, IronPython, ...) you're using, etc. so you shouldn't rely on it.

It could also be a disadvantage because a small slice of a huge slice would keep the huge slice alive because it's "lazy" evaluated, so in my opinion they were right that they didn't implement it that way.

However you can do it yourself, @georg already proposed a solution but given that `__cmp__` isn't supported in python-3.x anymore I'll present another (yet similar) solution that works independant of the python version:

```
class SubString(object):
    # slots reduce the memory overhead of the instances
    __slots__ = ('str_', 'startidx')

    def __init__(self, str_, startidx):
        self.str_ = str_
        self.startidx = startidx

    # sorted only requires "<" to be implemented so we only need __lt__
    def __lt__(self, other):
        # temporarly create explicit substrings but only temporaries for the comparison
        return self.str_[self.startidx:] < other.str_[other.startidx:]

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.str_[self.startidx:]
```

These should be pretty memory-efficient but it will take a while to sort them but at least I had no memory problems.

I tested it with:

```
import random
import string

# create a long random string
mystr = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(100000))

# sort the instances
sortedsubstr = sorted(SubString(mystr, i) for i in range(len(mystr)))
```

Comment: Yeah, right, replaced cmp with lt in my code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a list of "slice" objects that only hold start/end indexes of the underlying data. Once you implement `__lt__` for these objects, you can sort that list. Example:

```
class Slice(object):
    def __init__(self, src, start, end):
        self.src = src
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        for n in xrange(self.start, self.end):
            yield self.src[n]

    def __lt__(self, other):
        s1, s2 = iter(self), iter(other)

        for x1, x2 in zip(s1, s2):
            if x1 < x2:
                return True
            if x1 > x2:
                return False

        s1empty = s2empty = False

        try:
            next(s1)
        except StopIteration:
            s1empty = True
        try:
            next(s2)
        except StopIteration:
            s2empty = True

        return s1empty and not s2empty


huge = 'abcdef' * 10
hlen = len(huge)

slices = [Slice(huge, n, hlen) for n in xrange(hlen)]
slices += slices

slices.sort()

for s in slices:
    for char in s:
        print char,
    print
```

This code doesn't allocate any memory except for (tiny) `Slice` objects themselves.